# что можно сделать для обеспечения потокобезопасности?

Tags: c, многопоточность

Здравствуйте. Был на собеседовании... В итоге озадачили следующим вопросом (примерно).

Вот, допустим, есть сишная либа в исходниках... Там куча глобальных переменных... Но она писалась не под многопоточные приложения... Что можно сделать, чтобы обеспечить более-менее адекватное использование этой либы в многопоточных приложениях, притом, что существенно менять исходники нельзя(да и слишком непосильная задача будет)? В общем, что-то нужно сделать с глобальными переменными, но что?

Comment: а можете кусок кода привести? не совсем въехал

Comment: А может глобальные переменные в многопоточном доступе используются только по чтению? (Там, настройки какие-то, которые делаются один раз на старте). Или по записи тоже? От этого многое зависит.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Один [наивный] подход - разнести вызовы этих функций из разных потоков *по времени*, т.е. заоболочить каждый вызов в критическую секцию. Однако имейте в виду, что такой подход не будет применим, если рассматриваемые глобальные переменные используются для сохранения состояния *между* вызовами этих функций. Если учесть, что в 9 случаях из 10 глобальные переменные заводятся именно для таких целей, применимость такого подхода выглядит сомнительной.

  Например (не ходя далеко за примером), сериализация вызовов стандартной функции `strtok` из разных потоков через критическую секцию никак не сделает ее работоспособной в многопоточной среде, ибо она использует глобальную переменную для сохранения состояния между вызовами.

  (Интересно было бы поспорить на тему того, можно ли таким образом адаптировать к многопоточности функцию `rand()`, которая, как известно, тоже обладает сохраняемым между вызовами состоянием :) )
- Второй подход - разнести конфликты между этими функциями *в пространстве* (в памяти). А именно: объявить все глобальные переменные, как *thread local*, используя С11 спецификатор `_Thread_local`. Это не потребует какого-то существенного изменения исходников. (Многие пре-С11 компиляторы С давно предоставляют аналогичную функциональность в качестве расширения - тот же `__thread` в GCC или `__declspec(thread)` в MSVC.)

  Этот подход несравнимо более надежен, но опять же, вопрос тут в том, устроит ли вас ситуация, когда в каждом потоке функции библиотеки будут вести себя "изолированным" образом по отношению к глобальным данным, т.е. устроят ли вас, к примеру, изолированные счетчики открытых файлов, изолированные глобальные флаги состояния и т.п. Так что работоспособность такого подхода тоже не является очевидной.

Comment: видимо не мой это уровень, эх... шарить бы в этих самых критических секциях... а чем thread_local принципиально отличается от обычной локальной переменной которую мы создаем в функции, вызываемой в другом потоке?

Comment: Хочется всё в класс загнать. И вроде не очень существенное изменение?

Answer (score 2):

Много зависит от самой библиотеки, если библиотека обрабатывает данные в памяти, то использование мьютексов легко реализуемый вариант.
Но если библиотека работает с системой ввода/вывода то лучше реализовать отдельный поток для работы с библиотекой и работать с ним через мьютексы и сигнальные переменые.